# MongoDB where-in other collection clause

Tags: mongodb

Does MongoDB support something like?

select * from coll_a where code in (select code from coll_b)?

It has $in operator, but seems not doing in that way.

Comment: please share your code because $in works the same.

Comment: I think you are looking for `$lookup` operator

Comment: @Vao, yes, but when i use $match to filter by foreign table criteria, it is very very slow. (i need to retrieve 1k of record out of 10M sharded record)

Comment: e.g.  very slow query even user.country is indexed. I am wondering lookup with match using foreign table attribute cannot hit the index.

db.bigtable.aggregate( [  
    {$lookup:{ from: "user", localField:
               "user_code", foreignField: "code",as: "user"}},   
    {$match: {"user.country":"US" } }] )

Therefore, i am trying to find some alternatives, like

select * from bigtable where user_code in (select code from user where country = "US")

As bigtable.user_code & user.country are indexed, the query should be very fast

Comment: use corsor.explain() to check if it uses indexes. provide sample data please. btw - `join` is almost always more efficient then `in` in SQL